# how to use Swift Framework In Unity?

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, frameworks

I'm trying to use an iOS native framework inside Unity, but I don't know how.

Inside my C# script, I call a native function like this :

```
[DllImport ("__Internal")]
    private static extern void framework_hello();
    void Start () {
        framework_hello();
    }
```

Below is my folder structure in unity

Assets -> Plugins -> iOS -> SampleFramework.framework

But when I deploy my app on iPad, xCode showing this error :

```
Showing Recent Messages
  "_framework_hello", referenced from:
      _FrameworkBridge_framework_hello_m2723398483 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _FrameworkBridge_framework_hello_m2723398483)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Try signup to [Moblyft](http://moblyft.com/), download their UnitySDK, you should find many helpful things from there.